# my app crash after i install react-native-blob-util

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, blob

first i have error
`unable to resolve module react-native-blob-util`

after i install react-native-blob-util and i link, i get error in xcode `Build input file cannot be found`

[image: ERROR XCODE]

i dont know, what should i do. i've been looking for answer at google, youtube, stackoverflow but no one has the same problem.
i already uninstall, reset chache, and no changes.
can someone help me?

Comment: There is no library linking for iOS packages. Some of them require adding something to `Podfile`. Few things you can try:
1. Ensure that you followed all steps in package installation guide,  
2. Remove node_modules  
3. Remove `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` folder  
3. Install node_modules  
4. Run `cd ios && pod install`  
5. Build the app